# useDelimeter(",") not working

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I have a text file that holds data like this:

```
Jones,Mary,903452
4342,2.5,A
3311,4,B+
```

I'm using Scanner to read the file.  This is my code:

```
while(reader.hasNextLine())
{ 
        reader.useDelimiter(",");

        String lastN = reader.next();
        String firstN = reader.next();
        String id = reader.nextLine();

        String course1 = reader.next();
        double credits = reader.nextDouble();
        String grade = reader.nextLine();
}
```

But when I print the line on the console, the `,` on the last part of the line doesn't get delimited and it prints like this:

```
Jones, Mary, ,903452
4342, 2.5, ,A
6.5, ,3.569
```

My toString method on my class:

```
public String toString() {
  return lastName + ", " + firstName + ", " + idNo + "\n"
            + courseOne + ", " + credits + ", " + grade;
```

I'm searched around for a solution.  I tried `reader.useDelimiter("[,]")` and `reader.useDelimiter(",|,")` but still gives me the same output.  How can I fix this?

Comment: You are not skipping the last , by using nextLine() and it is including the preceding , in the input.  I bet if you do System.out.println(id) it will be ",903452" because nextLine only guarantees removal of trailing delimiter.  Try:
String id = reader.next();
reader.nextLine();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the `Scanner`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()):

> This method returns the **rest** of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

(Emphasis mine) This means that the whole rest of the line is returned, **including delimiters**. Setting `id` to `reader.next()` wouldn't work because it sucks up *everything* until the next delimiter. A better solution would be to make it accept line breaks as a delimiter, like so:

```
reader.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
```